# GARCH forecasting

Tags: forecasting, garch

```
model=ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH",garchOrder=c(1,1)),mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(1,1),include.mean=TRUE),distribution.model='sstd',start.pars = list(?), fixed.pars = list(?))
modelfit=ugarchfit(spec=model,data=r)
modelfor=ugarchforecast(modelfit,data=NULL,n.ahead=10,n.roll=0,out.sample=0)
```

I am forecasting future returns and vol for a fund for which I have only have 150 historical returns of monthly data. I was confused as what to put in the fixed and start parameters in **ugarchspec** function. Also if I want to do Monte Carlo simulation and forecast, is it possible? I found a function `ugarchsim` but didn't get how it works.

Comment: Always helpful to spell out which language you are using, presumably R.

Comment: Please review advice in the Help Center on software-related questions. This has some statistical flavour in so far as you seem uncertain about what you are doing and why but in general questions asking for code only would be off-topic here.

Comment: @NickCox Its not the code that I am asking for but I want to know if the forecast I am doing using the above code is right as the VaR that I get using this forecast is -0.5% monthly while when I estimate the historical Var and parametric VaR, they seem to be coming around -2.63% monthly.

Comment: you probably should post your question to rsig-finance.  Many experts, including the packages author, respond there.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the parameters are optional. Documentation to ugarchspec says that start parameters are not required unless the algorithm fail converging. Nevertheless, they may be set e.g. as start.pars=list(beta1=0.9, alpha1=0.05), which are all sensible values for "volatility with low volatility".

Once you fit the model and get the parameters, the forecasting is done in a way that you need to input the previous-day returns and volatilities. It is done through *ugarchforecast*, but you need to adjust your code for it to be useful.

```
model=ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH",garchOrder=c(1,1)),mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(1,1),include.mean=TRUE),distribution.model='norm', start.pars = list(beta1=0.93, omega=0.0000004, alpha=0.05))

modelfit=ugarchfit(spec=model,data=r, solver="hybrid", out.sample=20)

modelforecast<-ugarchforecast(modelfit, data = NULL, n.ahead = 1, n.roll = 5, external.forecasts = list(mregfor = NULL, vregfor = NULL))
```

The default rule for ugarchforecast is that only the first period prediction is based on the previous values, while for longer forecast the *un*conditional variance is calculated. So if you want to feed previous values into the forecast (which you probably want), then 
**out.sample** must be specified as an argument of **ugarchfit**. In **ugarchforecast**, the n.roll must be also specified, and it cannot be longer than the out.sample. Documentation for rugarch discusses this in detail.

Comment: Hi, can you throw some light on how what should I change in my code. Thanks

Comment: Like I want to know how can I generate randomness in forecast as the VaR I get using this is very less as compared to historical and parametric. Thanks

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect this. Without the out.sample, the forecast is constant.